# AngularJs - Filter to echo a string if model is true

Tags: angularjs, filter, directive

I'm trying to figure out how to make a filter that will echo out a value if the model passed in through the scope is true.

So for example, my database returns true or false to: thing.hearted. I would like a filter that will echo out "hearted" if thing.hearted === true. Ideally it would work like this:

{{thing.hearted | heartedFilter}}

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do like this.

```
angular.module('MyModule', []).
  filter('heartedFilter', function() {
    return function(input) {
      if(input === true)
        return "hearted"
      return "";
    }
  });
```